# How to average values in JSON after grouping within a group in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, average

I have a json file with the following data which I would like to group by Year , Theme and then average values on each theme. Can someone help me with this? I have grouped by date and then theme but struggling after that.

> [
> {"Bid":"BidTest1","QNo":"1","Score":"0.7","Theme":"Social Value","QDate":"01/01/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidTest1","QNo":"2","Score":"0.5","Theme":"Tech Mgt","QDate":"01/01/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidTest1","QNo":"3","Score":"0.8","Theme":"Agile","QDate":"01/01/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidTest1","QNo":"4","Score":"0.7","Theme":"Social Value","QDate":"01/01/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidTest456","QNo":"1","Score":"0.5","Theme":"Tech Mgt","QDate":"03/04/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidTest456","QNo":"2","Score":"0.7","Theme":"Social Value","QDate":"03/04/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidTest456","QNo":"3","Score":"0.5","Theme":"Agile","QDate":"03/04/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidHO","QNo":"1","Score":"0.8","Theme":"Agile","QDate":"06/10/2021"},
> {"Bid":"BidHO","QNo":"2","Score":"0.7","Theme":"Social Value","QDate":"06/10/2021"}
> ]

The code I have used for grouping it is

```js
let result1 = dataQ1.reduce((state1, current1 ) => {
let {QDate, Theme} = current1;

let date = state1[QDate] || (state1[QDate] = {});
let themeArr = date[Theme] || (date[Theme] = []);
// let monthArr = yearObj[month] || (yearObj[month] = []);

themeArr.push(current1);
return state1;
}, {});
```

This gives me an object with objects containing arrays for each Theme. I need to create a chart grouped by Month, Theme and mark the respective average values per theme.[Final Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0yN.png).[Final Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NusBe.png)

Could someone please guide me on how to go about this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly change your reducing function to make it easier to compute averages:

```js
let groupedDataQ1 = dataQ1.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    let {QDate, Theme} = item;
    accumulator[Theme] = accumulator[Theme] || {};
    // i'm assuming your dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format -> we extract mm/yyyy
    let month = QDate.slice(-7);
    (accumulator[Theme][month] = accumulator[Theme][month] || []).push(item);

    return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Now you have as keys the Themes, and each Theme is an object that, for each month, has an array of corresponding values. So, if you want to compute the average Scores for Theme "Agile" in April 2021 you would simply do

```js
let agile_april_data = groupedDataQ1['Agile']['04/2021'];
let agile_april_avg_score = agile_april_data.reduce((val, item) => val + parseFloat(item.Score),0) / agile_april_data.length
```

The reason why I decided to change the first term of the grouping function (you group first by date [leaving aside the fact that you keep the day in the key], and then by Theme, while I do the other way around) is because in the screenshot examples you provided, the Theme is the *series* over which the computations are performed - so, for each Theme, one line in the plot and one table in the tabular data. What happens if, for a month, you don't have any data for a specific Theme? You would need to perform a big amount of checks, while in this approach you only need to iterate over the object keys.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I had to make a small modification to the reduce function. I used agile_april_data.reduce((val, item) => parseFloat(val) + parseFloat(item.Score) ,0) as it was showing NaN when there were multiple rows to be averaged.

Comment: @SubadhraThangavelu glad it helped! You’re right - I just realized you have strings in the Scores. You can either parse them while you average like you did (though you only need to parse `item.Score` since `val` is already a number) or (maybe better?) parse them in the grouping function. If your problem is solved remember to accept the answer!